# Find ranges of Roman Numerals in SQL

Tags: python, sql, r, range, average

I am looking for a way to find the ranges in a SQL statement.

My data looks like this

```
         COUNTRY PROTEIN  MG
1          China    42.8  II
2          China    42.3 III
3          China    41.9 III
4  United States    40.0  IV
5          China    43.2   I
6          China    42.5  IV
7          China    42.9 III
8          China    45.9  VI
9          Japan    42.3  VI
10 United States    40.9 III
```

I am currently running a statement like this where I get the average for the protein values but I do not know how to go about the range of the roman numerals

```
select COUNTRY, avg(PROTEIN), MG from data group by COUNTRY
```

I would like my output to look like this (NOT CORRECT NUMBERS JUST AN EXAMPLE)

```
COUNTRY MEAN MG_RANGE
China 42.3 I-III
United States 45.2 I-VI
```

I have this file as a CSV so I am open to alternatives in R and Python that would give me the same output. It could be numerical as well whatever output is easiest.

Comment: why no just convert roman numerals to standard (arabic) ones, then you will be able to use any math sql functions?

Comment: Note that you've left out the desired output.  Please add it.  Would you want 3-4 or III-IV or (two columns: 'MG_MIN' and 'MG_MAX') with 3 and 4, or III and IV?

Comment: Sorry just updated that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, the *utils* package has a non-exported function `.roman2numeric()`, for converting character Roman numerals to their respective numeric values. We can convert from Roman to numeric then aggregate to find the range within a country.

```
(dat$MG2 <- utils:::.roman2numeric(as.character(dat$MG))
#  2   3   3   4   1   4   3   6   6   3 
dat
#         COUNTRY PROTEIN  MG MG2
# 1         China    42.8  II   2
# 2         China    42.3 III   3
# 3         China    41.9 III   3
# 4  UnitedStates    40.0  IV   4
# 5         China    43.2   I   1
# 6         China    42.5  IV   4
# 7         China    42.9 III   3
# 8         China    45.9  VI   6
# 9         Japan    42.3  VI   6
# 10 UnitedStates    40.9 III   3
```

And to (arbitrarily) find the range of `MG2` per country, we can do

```
aggregate(MG2 ~ COUNTRY, dat, range)
#        COUNTRY MG2.1 MG2.2
# 1        China     1     6
# 2        Japan     6     6
# 3 UnitedStates     3     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that will both parse and generate Roman numerals: http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/romanNumerals.py/30112817/romanNumerals.py

Convert your input Roman numerals to integers (using `romanNumeral.parseString` from the linked code), compute the min and max values to get the range, then use `makeRomanNumeral` in the linked code to convert the range values back to Roman nums.

Or if you don't have that many different Roman values to deal with, just define a dict that maps the Roman numerals to their actual values, and you can skip using the parser. Something like this:

```
romanLookup = {
  'I' : 1,
  'II' : 2,
  'III' : 3,
  'IV' : 4,
  'V' : 5,
  'VI' : 6,
  'VII' : 7,
  'VIII' : 8,
  'IX' : 9,
  'X' : 10,
  'XI' : 11,
  'XII' : 12,
  'XIII' : 13,
  'XIV' : 14,
  'XV' : 15,
  'XVI' : 16,
  'XVII' : 17,
  'XVIII' : 18,
  'XIX' : 19,
  'XX' : 20,
}
```

Here is your program:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import namedtuple
DataRec = namedtuple("DataRec", "country protein mg")

#123456789012345678901234567890
# X             X       X   X
data = """\
1          China    42.8  II
2          China    42.3 III
3          China    41.9 III
4  United States    40.0  IV
5          China    43.2   I
6          China    42.5  IV
7          China    42.9 III
8          China    45.9  VI
9          Japan    42.3  VI
10 United States    40.9 III""".splitlines()

suppress=object()
def splitAt(cols,fns):
    last = 0
    slices = []
    for c in cols:
        slices.append(slice(last,c))
        last = c+1
    return lambda s: [fn(s[sl]) for sl,fn in zip(slices,fns) 
                        if fn is not suppress]
splitter = splitAt([2,16,24,28], 
                    [suppress, str.strip, float, str.strip])

recs = [DataRec(*splitter(d)) for d in data]

romanLookup = {
  'I' : 1,
  'II' : 2,
  'III' : 3,
  'IV' : 4,
  'V' : 5,
  'VI' : 6,
  'VII' : 7,
  'VIII' : 8,
  'IX' : 9,
  'X' : 10,
  'XI' : 11,
  'XII' : 12,
  'XIII' : 13,
  'XIV' : 14,
  'XV' : 15,
  'XVI' : 16,
  'XVII' : 17,
  'XVIII' : 18,
  'XIX' : 19,
  'XX' : 20,
}

# sort and group data by country
recs.sort(key=lambda x: x.country)
grouped = groupby(recs, key=lambda x: x.country)

# for each country group, compute average protein and min/max mg
for country,countryRecs in grouped:
    datatuples = list(countryRecs)
    mg_vals = [r.mg for r in datatuples]
    ave = sum(r.protein for r in datatuples)/len(datatuples)
    min_mg = min(mg_vals, key=romanLookup.__getitem__)
    max_mg = max(mg_vals, key=romanLookup.__getitem__)
    if min_mg == max_mg:
        print "%s, %.2f, %s" % (country, ave, min_mg)
    else:
        print "%s, %.2f, %s-%s" % (country, ave, min_mg, max_mg)
```

Prints:

```
China, 43.07, I-VI
Japan, 42.30, VI
United States, 40.45, III-IV
```

Comment: R also has the ability to go back and forth between Roman numerals loaded by default in the `utils` package. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116763/convert-roman-numerals-to-numbers-in-r

Comment: Can you show me some code to convert and find the ranges though?

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to convert the ranges, just use `romanLookup.__getitem__` as the key function for getting the min and max MG values.

Comment: Ok But how can I get the ranges from those values?

Comment: Note that reporting the min and max values as, for example with China, "I-IV" implies that *all* of the values from I to IV are present; but there is no guarantee that, just because I and IV exist that II and III will also exist.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing