# R remove roman numerals from column

Tags: r, substring

I have a table in R with the following information. Some rows in `employee` have roman numerals, some do not:

```
employee <- c('JOHN SMITH II','PETER RABBIT','POPE GREGORY XIII', 'MARY SUE IV')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800, 100000)
employee_df <- data.frame(employee, salary)
> employee_df
           employee salary
1     JOHN SMITH II  21000
2      PETER RABBIT  23400
3 POPE GREGORY XIII  26800
4       MARY SUE IV 100000
```

How would I remove the roman numerals so that `employee_df$employee` would be the follwing?

```
JOHN SMITH    PETER RABBIT    POPE GREGORY   MARY SUE
```

Comment: You could use `as.roman()` to ensure that you are hitting real roman numerals. This would be safer than a regex. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116763/convert-roman-numerals-to-numbers-in-r

Comment: `XI` for instance is a valid name, what do you do in that circumstance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
employee_df$employee <-gsub('^([0-9]+)|([IVXLCM]+)\\.?$','',employee_df$employee)
```

Output:

```
       employee salary
1   JOHN SMITH   21000
2  PETER RABBIT  23400
3 POPE GREGORY   26800
4     MARY SUE  100000
```

Or cleaner:

```
#Code2
employee_df$employee <- trimws(gsub('^([0-9]+)|([IVXLCM]+)\\.?$','',employee_df$employee))
```

Output:

```
      employee salary
1   JOHN SMITH  21000
2 PETER RABBIT  23400
3 POPE GREGORY  26800
4     MARY SUE 100000
```

The numeric component of regex is not necessary (Many thanks **@BenBolker**). You can use:

```
#Code3
employee_df$employee <- trimws(gsub('([IVXLCM]+)\\.?$','',employee_df$employee))
```

And obtain the same result.

Comment: what's the `^([0-9]+)` part of the regex for ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker It is a way to take care of numbers if they are present!

Comment: @BenBolker But is not necessary. I will update the post!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what you say then you do *not* want to remove the roman numerals in the string with `POPE`. If that's correct then a way to remove all other numerals is this:

```
sub("^(?!\\bPOPE\\b)(.*?)\\s[IVXLCM]+$", "\\1", employee_df$employee, perl = T)
[1] "JOHN SMITH"        "PETER RABBIT"      "POPE GREGORY XIII" "MARY SUE"
```

Here we are using negative lookahead `(?!...)`asserting that the strings must not include the substring `POPE`, and backreference `\\1` to 'recollect' whatever is matched prior to the sequence of roman numerals at the end of the string.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that we do want to remove them for `POPE`. I've changed my original question.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
employee_df %>%
        mutate(employee = str_remove(employee, "\\s+[IVXLCM]+"))
```